# How to set the behavior for Pathauto when a duplicate exists?

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I'm creating a Drupal 7 site which will consist of information about many different organizations across North America. The profiles will be submitted by the organizations themselves and it is very likely that there will be duplicate names.

What I'd like to do is have Pathauto create the url: `orgs/OrganizationName` for the first such organization and after this create: `orgs/OrganizationName-City`.

Is there any way to change how Pathauto behaves when duplicates are found?

Comment: there is an option to define the pattern of the alias have you tried that?

Comment: Yes of course, what I'm asking is is there a way to define a second alias when the first results in a url that already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a module and use the hook_pathauto_alias_alter function to override the path alias before saving it.

```
function mymodule_pathauto_alias_alter(&$alias, &$context) {

  $temp = $alias;
  $newalias = pathauto_alias_uniquify($temp, $context['source'], $context['language']);
  if ($newalias !=$alias)
  {
    $alias .= $context['data']['node']->field_city[$context['data']['node']->language][0]['value'];
  }

}
```

The pathauto_alias_uniquify function checks if there is an alias already existing and if it does then would return the updated alias and if not return the same alias. now the one you get it different from the one we already have then we would could append the city name to the alias.

I have created a field called city with a field machine name field_city you will have to change your values accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Mohammed, I was hoping that there was a module already that would do this for me but failing that I guess I'll just make my own (and submit it to Drupal if I can work out how to alter the existing forms).

Comment: the one problem with your code is that pathauto_alias_uniquify doesn't return the updated alias name but it is put in `$temp` by reference.

Comment: have you checked it? because when I tested it, it returns the new alias.

Comment: I have, however perhaps there we're running different versions and there was some change. I'm on `7.x-1.2`. Not a huge change anyway, it just threw me off (`if ($temp != $alias)`...)